# Dask partition information during apply/map exceptions

Tags: python, exception, dask

Say I have some custom files I've read into a data bag using dask.bag.read_text then I do .map(foo) on the resulting bag. If foo throws an exception is there any way to gather information on which particular file it exploded on? Is this information accessible inside foo or is there something I can set so it's included in the stack track?

Comment: Are any of the techniques here of use?  http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/debugging.html

Comment: Not for the specific thing I want. Getting the stack trace is helpful but it doesn't help me find the specific file that caused my code to explode. At the moment I'm just having to download the group of files it was operating on and run locally, which is much more time consuming than just immediately being able to download the file.

Comment: You might be able to get more information by recreating the error locally.  See http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/debugging.html#rerun-failed-task-locally .  Short answer though is that "no, dask.bag can not tell you the inputs to previous tasks."  You might also try some of the options like `errors='ignore'` as well.